# Ruby on rails : Issue with Params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters

I'm developing a job board where the companies can submit job ads With jobdescriptions_controller, I also have an uuid field as ID for the outside world called "applyjobid", but now for the outside world I have created jobdetails_controller in order to find the jobdescription.

So, when I goto http://localhost:3000/jobdetails/show?applyjobid=54da4118-0ba3-4375-ae87-6fa32201a369

I have this error : ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /jobdetails/show
Couldn't find Jobdescription with 'id'=54da4118-0ba3-4375-ae87-6fa32201a369

If I go to http://localhost:3000/jobdetails/show?applyjobid=1 it works !!! but I really want to use uuid.

If you can tell me what is the problem, it would be very appreciated, thanks in advance.

Schema.rb

```
  create_table "jobdescriptions", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "applyjobid"
    t.string   "job_title"
    t.string   "department"
    t.text     "shift"
    t.string   "work_location"
    t.string   "position_supervisor"
    t.string   "supervisor_position_supervisor"
    t.decimal  "rate_pay"
    t.text     "benefits"
    t.text     "other_benefits"
    t.text     "job_summary"
    t.text     "job_duties"
    t.text     "tasks"
    t.text     "results"
    t.text     "responsibilities"
    t.text     "knowledge"
    t.text     "skills"
    t.text     "abilities"
    t.text     "physical_requirement"
    t.text     "work_envir_condition"
    t.text     "protective_clothing_and_devices_required"
    t.text     "tools_or_equipment_required"
    t.text     "qualifications"
    t.text     "education_and_training"
    t.text     "license_certification"
    t.text     "experience"
    t.text     "aptitudes_interests_temperament"
    t.text     "roles_relationships"
    t.text     "supervisory_responsibility"
    t.text     "advancement_promotion_opportunities"
    t.string   "internal_comment"
    t.string   "submited_by"
    t.string   "approved_by"
    t.string   "statut"
    t.date     "from_date"
    t.date     "end_date"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

jobdescriptions_controller.rb

```
class JobdescriptionsController < ApplicationController
  layout 'application'
  def new
    @jobdescription = Jobdescription.new
  end
  def create
    @jobdescription = current_user.jobdescriptions.create(jobdescription_params)
    redirect_to new_jobdescription_path
  end
private
  def jobdescription_params
    params.require(:jobdescription).permit(:applyjobid, :job_title,  )
  end
end
```

jobdetails_controller.rb

```
class JobdetailsController < ApplicationController
  layout 'application'

  def show
    @jobdetail = Jobdescription.find(params[:applyjobid])
  end


end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do


  resources :tests


  devise_for :users
  resources :timesheets
  resources :expenses
  resources :jobdescriptions
  resources :jobdetails
  root :to => 'dashbords#index'
```

thanks.

Comment: Your `routes.rb` should be prepared for that situation. You have change it and create access to particular page you want with `applyjobid` (better idea for that name is `apply_job_id`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's wrong here is you are finding by id as you are using find, and you are passing applyjobid
So you have to use find_by_applyjobid

try this

```
def show
   @jobdetail = Jobdescription.find_by_applyjobid(params[:applyjobid])
end
```

Comment: sure, hope it helps you.

Comment: I did what you told me to do, and ... It works perfectly, thanks a lot for your quick response.